# What is the sum of all possible integer values of the leading cooefficient of $P(x)$?

Tags: polynomials

Given

1. For every $x \in \mathbb{R},  P(x) \neq 0$;
2. $P(x)$ is a second degree polynomial;
3. $P(1) = 8$ and $P(2) = 2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By $(2)$
$$ P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
with $a\ne 0$.
By $(1)$, certainly $a>0$, but more importantly, $P(x_0)\ge 0$ where $x_0=-\frac b{2a}$ is the point of minimum of $P$. This boils down to
$$ a\frac {b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{-b^2}{2a}+c\ge0$$
or:
$$ b^2-4ac\le 0.$$
Finally,  $(3)$ gives us two linear equations in three unknowns:
$$ a+b+c=8$$
$$ 4a+2b+c=2.$$
You can use these to express $b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$. Plug the resulting expression into the inequality and find out for which $a$ the inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of solutions
of the form
$P(x)
=(ax+b)^2+c^2
$
where
$2 \le a^2 \le 18$,
$b
=-3(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{a}{2})
$,
$c^2
=-\dfrac{1}{4a^2}(a^2-18)(a^2-2)
$.

Theleading coefficient is
$a^2$ where
$2 \le a^2 \le 18$
so the sum is
$2+3+...+18
=18(19)/2-1
=170
$.

If we want
$P(x) = 0$ for some $x$ then
$a^2 = 2$ or $a^2 = 18$.

Derivation.

From 1 and 2,
$P(x)
=(ax+b)^2+c^2
$.

From 3,
$(a+b)^2+c^2 = 8,
(2a+b)^2+c^2 = 2
$.

$6
=(a+b)^2-(2a+b)^2
=(-a)(3a+2b)
$
so
$2b
=-\dfrac{6}{a}-3a
$,
$b
=-\dfrac{3}{a}-\dfrac{3a}{2}
=-3(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{a}{2})
$,
$a+b
=-\dfrac{3}{a}-\dfrac{a}{2}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
c^2
&=8-(a+b)^2\\
&=8-(-\dfrac{3}{a}-\dfrac{a}{2})^2\\
&=8-(\dfrac{9}{a^2}+3+\dfrac{a^2}{4})\\
&=-(\dfrac{9}{a^2}-5+\dfrac{a^2}{4})\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{4a^2}(36-20a^2+a^4)\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{4a^2}(a^2-18)(a^2-2)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$2 \le a^2 \le 18
$.

Then get $b$ and $c$.

For example,
try $a = 3, a^2 = 9$.

$c^2
=-\dfrac1{36}(-9)(7)
=\dfrac74
$.

$b = -3(\dfrac13+\dfrac32)
=-3(\dfrac{11}{6})
=-\dfrac{11}{2}
$.

$P(x)
=(3x-\dfrac{11}{2})^2+\dfrac74
$.

$P(1)
=(3-\dfrac{11}{2})^2+\dfrac74
=\dfrac{25}{4}+\dfrac74
=\dfrac{32}{4}
=8
$.

$P(2)
=(6-\dfrac{11}{2})^2+\dfrac74
=\dfrac1{4}+\dfrac74
=2
$.